# Как проверить умерла ли сессия?

Tags: php, сессия

Задача такая, что надо привязывать прокси к сессии каждой и после смерти сессии надо обновлять прокси которое было привязано к сессии.
Вопрос такой - как определить, что сессия мертва? Само закрытие браузера как определить?

Comment: Закрытие браузера вы не определите в 100% случаев. Можно надеяться на событие `onbeforeunload`, но оно не успеет отработать в случае пожара/метеорита/пропадания питания.

Comment: ну как-то же можно определить, что сессия умерла ?

Comment: Не знаю. Мне кажется, только какое-нибудь long-poll соединение с постоянным пингованием клиента с целью проверки, не отключился ли он еще. Либо же убивать сессию принудительно по истечении определенного срока бездействия.

Comment: А как определять бездействие? Отслеживать логи?

Comment: Вы про какую сессию говорите? Про браузерную? Каждый раз когда идет какой-то клиент-сервер запрос, на сервер приходит информация об этой сессии. Там вы можете запоминать время последнего запроса и при следующем проверять, не прошло ли больше, чем допустимо. Либо же кронами/чем угодно раз 1/5/10 минут проверять все открытые сессии и убивать те, которые были неактивны в течение какого-то времени.

Comment: ну я так и думал реализовать, только немного по другому. Используя бд, просто держать там таблицу с проксями и уже при каждой сессии проверять свободную проксю, если нету, то проверяем сессии которые уже привязаны к прокси, но тут момент опять как определять сессию которую из таблицы удалять, только если время или как раз бездействие смотреть.
Может просто есть проще варианты как определить мертвую сессию...

Comment: Мне этот кажется самым логичным. Храните время последней активности вместе с сессией и проверяйте, что разница между ним и текущим не превышает n. Хотя утверждать не буду, может кто-то что-то более дельное посоветует.

Comment: Я бы предложил задействовать оба механизма. Если вы факт закрытия вкладки в браузере считаете окончанием сессии, то повесить обработчик закрытия в JS и сообщать на сервер. Но если даже сообщения не было, то принудительно закрывать на сервере по таймауту. Дополнительно можно еще в браузере повесить какой нибудь таймер, который периодически будет вам слать сообщения что он еще запущен, таким образом вы сможете более точно обновлять время последнего использования сессии. Но тут то же надо быть аккуратным, не ставить слишком маленький таймаут

Comment: Вообще комп с открытой вкладкой могут отправить в гибернацию и скажем включить его только через неделю. Такой вариант то же надо предусмотреть. Т.е. быть готовым к тому, что к вам вернется сессия от которой по таймауту уже все отвязали. И выдать новую проксю как будто это новая сессия. Думаю ничего страшного в этом не будет.

Comment: Это уже слишком усложненная конструкция) Может я как-то неправильно объяснился или что. Мне просто надо держать список прокси 50-100 штук и выдавать каждой сессии проксю, но после ее смерти прокси-сервер надо обновить и выходит так, что непонятно как поймать этот момент смерти сессии чтобы обновить прокси уже для следущей сессии.
Может как-то можно по-другому каждому клиенту выдавать прокси, а не через сессию.

Comment: @Mike, Я тоже думал об этом. В этом вопрос и заключается. Что как лучше будет сделать привязку. 
Кроме сессии нету за что прицепиться для привязки прокси каждому юзеру индивидуально.
А проксей мало 50-100 штук и их надо постоянно обновлять после каждого юзера. Может есть другие варианты кроме сессий?
Ничего страшного в том, что у юзера сессия старая и она обновится и выдаст новую проксю

Comment: посмотрите в сторону веб-сокетов, если вам так уж необходимо знать точно, подключен клиент, или уже нет.